# TextField padding

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm working on this nametag designer project, and because the elements are later added to pdf, i need to know the EXACT placement on the tag.

TextField's are giving me some problems, cause the textfield "padding" changes when you change the fontsize.

[image]

I either need to remove the "padding" or get the x,y position of the text inside the TextField.

Leading test:
[image]

Any ideas on this! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what "padding" you need, but you can get all offsets with this methods: [getCharBoundaries()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getCharBoundaries%28%29), [getLineMetrics()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#getLineMetrics%28%29).

Comment: Seems like it's not possible. See how theres no property for the top left position of the char: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html

Comment: @user648753 It sure is possible and if I am understanding what you want it is the leading property you need to adjust. "leading" would be the padding on the top of the text. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextLineMetrics.html#leading

Comment: @The_asMan Thank you SO much, I won't be able to confim it before monday, but it seems solid.

Comment: @The_asMan Leading only seems to apply for multiple lines of text. See the update for details